# How do I inject the Symfony DI Container itself into a service?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to configure a service to automatically have an existing DI Container injected into it. My `ContentQuery` class already `extends` another class, so it must instead implement the `ContainerAwareInterface` and configure the actual injection using a `call` block:

```
<services>
  <service id="my_module.model.content_query" class="MyModule\Model\ContentQuery">
    <call method="setContainer">
      <argument type="service" id="container" />
    </call>
  </service>
</services>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to identify the Container itself in the XML. Using the above config, I get this error:

> the service "my_module.model.content_query" has a dependency on a non-existent service "container"

I would rather just do this in PHP, which I think I could figure out pretty easily, but the decision to use XML is out of my hands at this time. So is there a way to identify the Container instance as a service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp. About a minute after posting I figured it out. :P

Just needed to specify `id="service_container"` instead of just "container":

```
<services>
  <service id="my_module.model.content_query" class="MyModule\Model\ContentQuery">
    <call method="setContainer">
      <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
    </call>
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: app/console debug:container is your friend